# Lock USB pendrives to specific computers

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

We have pendrives for data operators, they look at sensitive data and the pendrives are for work use in case they need to transfer data between their computers (Their network is isolated and is not able to access Internet or share file servers and I have yet to configure a file server for their use, no hardware yet)

These pendrives are not supposed to leave the office nor be used on other computers. In the event that someone unintentionally or intentionally takes the USB home or tries to plug it into a different computer, they would be able to access the data.

Is there a way to "lock" these usb pendrives to be used only on specific computers?

I tried to research something about it but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Gracias!

Comment: Sounds like your trying to solve the problem an incorrect way. These drives should be secured in a safe. The inventory of said drives should be done daily before the last person goes home. You skip the fact somebody could bring their own drive in, copy the data, and walk out. You can encrypt data to a certain computer, but that would make it impossible to ever read, on a different installation of Windows.  Don't try to invent the wheel again, use the check-in check-out procedure.

Comment: I can block unknown USB pendrives on the computer side and just allow these but I'd like to "lock" down the pendrive itself so it only works on these specific computers. I.E if they plug it in elsewhere its encrypted or just doesn't show. I think there are scripts to put inside the pendrive itself but I'm not 100% sure. Maybe someone here has done it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what OS you are using, but if it's Windows 7 or 8 you can use Bitlocker or EFS to encrypt the entire drive or folders and files on them.  You could probably use another encryption program to get the same results on a different OS.

EFS will only encrypt folders and files, bitlocker can encrypt the entire drive.  The EFS decryption key is tied to user accounts, bitlocker uses certificates.  As long as you prevent the user from taking the decryption key or certificate out of the office then the files on the removable drives would only be accessible on computers with the right account or certificate.

While the drive is not locked to the computer, the information on it will be inaccessible to anyone not on a computer with the proper decryption keys.

Answer (score 2):

If the security requirements are higher than the software means, where, in fact, there is risk of attack to a file systems for encryption/decryption keys are stored, or attack with trojan viruses aiming keyboard scans or both or something else, then you will need **Hardware** means of encryption. They are called *Pass encoders* with transparently encryption. It is an extra device inside your computer. Such as [Ancud](http://www.ancud.ru/enversion.html) produces:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Or some external USB coders, such as

[**Apricorn**](http://www.apricorn.com/products/hardware-encrypted-drives.html):

[image]

Or just have a look at the Pen Drives with inbuilt encryption and other related features such as :

- [**Kingfast**](http://www.tweaktown.com/reviews/6341/kingfast-32gb-secure-hardware-encrypted-usb-flash-drive-review/index.html)

[image]
[image]

- [**SecureUSB**](http://secureusb.com.au/?gclid=CL-Yidi3ub8CFZJbfgodMLoAZA)

[image]
[image]

- [**Alersec**](http://www.alertsec.com/?gclid=CLa15Nm3ub8CFQphfgodIgcAnA)

[image]

- [**Ironkey**](http://www.ironkey.com/en-US/encrypted-storage-drives/)

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you Could Do....
You Could get this particular Netgear NightHawk [https://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-Nighthawk-Gigabit-Support-Compatible/dp/B011AJYQ8Q?th=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011AJYQ8Q)

And It has an Option On the Website that you can get 1 Tb Hard Drive With It.
What You Need to Do Is to Turn off the wireless Option, Plug In the Hard Drive, and set it to only allow the computers you want into the local network. And If you Want you could put a hardware firewall on the ethernet input, and it would be secure so you could use it with an internet connection.

Summary:
Secure Network, Internet Optional but very secure with hardware firewall.
Allows only certain computers.
Has A 1 Tb Hard Drive for Storage, you could also if you want put a software encryption on it.

Super Secure Local or Internet Network.
Super Secure Storage
Pretty Awesome.

-Dane Wright (Same If you look at my Youtube Channel).